# d3.js - is it possible to draw and Histogram without the .map?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a big csv file, and am currently using the `dataset.map` function to get the values I need to be plotted in the histogram. However, this way removes all the other values bound to that particular data, and returns an array containing just the values.
Is it possible to plot the data without using the `.map`? this way I could use the values more easily to display maybe the name of the values or else.
Right now the function I'm using is:

```
var Peso = dataset.filter(function (d) { return d.Grazie == "Sans" })
    .map(function (i) { return (i.Peso)});
var histog = d3.layout.histogram()
        .bins(30)
        (Peso);
```

But without the `.map` I don't know how to call the "Peso" values in the `histog` variable.
Any hint or help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`.value()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Histogram-Layout#wiki-value) to specify an accessor, so in your case it would be something like

```
d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(30)
    .value(function(d) { return d.Peso; })
    (dataset);
```

You would still need to do the filtering though.

Comment: thanks it worked! :) I can't accept it as correct right now because of the site time counter, in a few I'll mark it